# Return Integer From Block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, block, game-center

I am attempting to return an integer from a block I am calling. You can see it below:

```
-(NSInteger)globalRecord
{
    __block NSInteger globalRecord = 0;
    
    [GKLeaderboard loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *leaderboards, NSError *error) {
        GKLeaderboard *globalTaps = nil;
        for (GKLeaderboard *lb in leaderboards) if ([lb.category isEqualToString:kGlobalLeaderboard]) globalTaps = lb;
        
        [globalTaps loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if ([scores count] != 0)
            {
                GKScore *topScore = [scores objectAtIndex:0];
                globalRecord = topScore.value;
                //42 here
            }
                        
        }];
    }];
    
    //0 here
    
    return globalRecord;
}
```

So I am trying to get the highest score from my leader-board in game center. I want my method to return the score once it's been received; however, it's not returning my score.

In the block it recognises the score, 42 in this case, however once we reach outside of the block and want to return the value, it's 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting zero because the return is actually called BEFORE the block's execution. To get the `globalRecord` value you should use a callback once the block `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` ends:

```
-(void)globalRecord
{
    __block NSInteger globalRecord = 0;

    [GKLeaderboard loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *leaderboards, NSError *error) {
        GKLeaderboard *globalTaps = nil;
        for (GKLeaderboard *lb in leaderboards) if ([lb.category isEqualToString:kGlobalLeaderboard]) globalTaps = lb;

        [globalTaps loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if ([scores count] != 0)
            {
                GKScore *topScore = [scores objectAtIndex:0];
                globalRecord = topScore.value;
                [self globalRecordRetrieved:globalRecord];
                //42 here
            }

        }];
    }];
}

- (void)globalRecordRetrieved:(NSInteger)record{
    NSLog(@"%d",record); //42 here
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a solution instead of only pointing out the problem like me. Two remarks: 1) The __block variable is not needed anymore. 2) The completion handler might be called on a different thread. To update UI components, one should use `performSelectorOnMainThread:...` or similar methods.

Comment: you are right the globalRecordRetrieved should be called with performSelectorOnMainThread, or he could switch to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /*do some UI safe stuff*/});`

Answer (score 4):

Both `loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler` and `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` work asynchronously. From the 
[documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKLeaderboard/loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler%3a):

> When this method is called, it creates a new background task to handle
>   the request. The method then returns control to your game. Later, when
>   the task is complete, Game Kit calls your completion handler. ...

This means that

```
[GKLeaderboard loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler:...]
```

returns before a value has been assigned to `globalRecord` in the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
-(NSInteger)globalRecord
{
    __block NSInteger globalRecord = 0;

     dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [GKLeaderboard loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *leaderboards, NSError *error) {
        GKLeaderboard *globalTaps = nil;
        for (GKLeaderboard *lb in leaderboards) if ([lb.category isEqualToString:kGlobalLeaderboard]) globalTaps = lb;

        [globalTaps loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if ([scores count] != 0)
            {
                GKScore *topScore = [scores objectAtIndex:0];
                globalRecord = topScore.value;
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
            }

        }];
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(sema);
    //42 here

    return globalRecord;
}
```

Be careful!

This example will block the thread that called this method